# Cant seem to import files using rails and less

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less

I cannot seem to figure out why my import statements aren't working.

i have a file located at /assets/stylesheets/config/load.css.less
and a file located at    /assets/stylesheets/config/global.css.less

inside of the config file i simply use @import "global.css.less";

the code is so simple that its baffling me why it's not working. nobody else seems to be having this problem, so it must be something really simple. Any ideas?

the error i get is

Less::ParseError: 'global_vars.css.less' wasn't found.

anybody who can help it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try using `@import "global"`?

Comment: yah i did. because the extension is css.less it forces me to specify extension. it only looks for global.less if i type global

Answer (score 0):

Less looks at the root of your assets directory for doing the `@import`, try changing:

`@import "global.css.less"`

to

`@import "config/global.css.less"`

and see if that works.